# Google Cloud Messaging GCM for Android and Push Notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm dealing with Eclipse Luna to build the web app (jsp,java) while dealing with Eclipse Juno to build the android app. Plus, i'm referring to this link as my tutorial http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

Registration id generated successfully in android device. But when run Java Application it gives following error.

```
RegId required: com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: To help you we need some code. Please post the _relevant_ parts of your code.

Comment: currently i'm applying this tutorial.... 

http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

Comment: This is probably either because you have missed out some permissions in the manifest or because you are using the wrong GCM register ID. Please post your full stack trace to pin point the problem. And double check the Google API console for wrong keys.

Comment: I'm using Google APIs Level 19. I'll edit this post and show the code. thanks

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ refer this link also

Comment: Have you obtained the server key from Google API console and did you insert it into your code? The example uses a dummy value.

Comment: i already obtained server key Google API console and insert it into my code

Comment: @Boopathi if u dont mind can u teach me how to put error in box like the one that u edit for me? tq

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your IP address is correctly listed in the list of "allowed IPs" for your particular server key in the Google API console.

To obtain your IP follow the link: http://www.ipcow.com/

To check the allowed list of IPs:

- Go to Google API Console.
- Select your project using the drop down on the upper left hand corner.
- Go to the API access tab.
- Find your "key for server apps" and click on the link "Edit allowed IPs" to the right hand side.
- Add your IP there. (Or leave it blank)

Note: If you leave the list of allowed IPs blank, any IP is allowed. But try it using your current IP (worked for me).

Comment: i get your idea and already obtained my IP address but how to check my IP is correctly listed in the list of "allowed IPs"?

Comment: After I change my IP adress this is the error shown :

[ errorCode=MismatchSenderId ]

Comment: Have you tried leaving the IP blank? And please check if the ids on the device and the id you are pushing the notification to are the same.

Comment: i've tried both (with IP and without IP). PLus,i've re-insert my GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID in app code while GOOGLE_SERVER_KEY in web app code but unfortunately it keep showing error message
 
[ errorCode=MismatchSenderId ]

Comment: This is what i get now.. 
[ messageId=0:1407225158322588%31e4cc17f9fd7ecd ]

Comment: Where do you get this? Did you receive it as notification?

Comment: supposely i have to get the notification..but the thing is only the icon of notification in the interface appear...in web service the message shown like this
 [ messageId=0:1407225158322588%31e4cc17f9fd7ecd ]

Comment: heyy...hi...i have a doubt regarding this.could u please help me out ?

Comment: Glad u replied...Am also dealing with a similar situation.I want to push messages from my server to app.I just started this module.Which ip has to be given while creating server key ?

Comment: If you are pushing notifications via http request use the browser key and in case you are pushing it using the `Sender` object in the google play services you will have to use a server key. Refer this: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html. And if you leave the IP blank any IP will be accepted

Comment: I'm referring to this tutorial http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/.Planning to do in a similar way

Comment: Yes. Just leave the IP blank and hopefully you will be fine